# codeigniter, library or helper can access through url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

In Codeigniter, there are library and helper.
I can access controller and its sub function. 
for eample.

```
login/getid
```

Is there any way to access library or helper through url?

**Update :** 
I made a captcha library in login controller. 
I want to use it in many other controller's view.
in view file, the captcha code should be like this,

```
<img src="/login/get_captcha" />
```

everytime I want to use captcha, I have to call login controller.

So, I thought that there should be better way to do this.
If library or helper can access through url, I can make this to helper.
can access another controller's view without loading login's controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a wrapper controller to access those functions exclusively and use your routes to utilize said URL's

Example: `yoursite.com/helper/geo/citiesNearZip/90210`

```
class helperController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper($this->uri->segment(1)); // geo helper in this example

        if($this->uri->segment(2))
        {
            $helper_method = $this->uri->segment(2);
        }
        else
        {
            show_404();
            return false;
        }

        // check if helper has function named after segment 2, function citiesNearZip($zip) in this example...
        if(function_exists($helper_method)
        {
            // Execute function with provided uri params, xss filter, secure, etc...
            // You would also want to grab all the remaining uri params and pass them as 
            // arguments to your helper function
            $helper_method();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: right, I can empty wrapper controller, and can access that. I know this. thanks.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. You are not able to error handle your url calls at all doing this - if "geo" is a helper that doesn't exist, the code will simply explode. It's a "neat hack", but bad coding

Comment: A simple check if `file_exists(APPPATH . '/helpers/' . $this->uri->segment(1) . '.php')` would suffice I imagine. 404 if it's missing. All code can be tuned for a use case. I don't think your paranoia here justified the downvote personally, but thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. This is simply not the way the framework was designed to work.

If you think you have to access a helper/library directly, then you're probably doing something wrong.

Can explain what you're trying to do? There must be a better way.